# Unable to make right URL structure with NGINX proxy

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have two application. One is a nextjs app and another is a WordPress app. Both are running in difference instances.

In order to serve my WordPress blog from my main site like https://example.com/blog, I have added the following proxy to my main site's nginx server configuration,

```
location ^~ /blog/ {
    http2_push_preload on;
    proxy_pass https://blog.exmaple.com/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Host blog.example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

If I click on any save button from the admin portal, then it removes the 'blog' word from the URL on next load like this 'https://exmaple.com/wp-admin/options-general.php?settings-updated=true' and gives a 404 in main site when it should be like 'https://example.com/blog/wp-admin/options-general.php?settings-updated=true'.

I have updated the WordPress URLs as well. And all other URLs such as homepage, blog posts, page, media etc. are working find.

What am I doing wrong here? Please feel free to ask for more information for clarification.

Comment: Even though the issue on this question (https://serverfault.com/questions/944231/nginx-proxy-pass-to-wordpress-site-for-site-com-blog-to-blog-site-com) is similar to my issue (not exactly same), the said solution in this isn't working either. Please help.

Comment: Go to WordPress General Settings and change the URL, as described in the [Moving WordPress documentation](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/moving-wordpress/#changing-your-domain-name-and-urls)

Comment: The URL are already changed and I also updated the wp-config file.

Comment: Then please provide all relevant information, don't let people guess blindly.

Comment: It was missed by mistake.

Comment: I can now access the home page. After using the solution mentioned in the question I linked in my first comment, it worked. It was my browser cache at that moment that made me think the homepage was not accessible. So, I have updated the question accordingly to the problem that is present now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did as workaround,

I redirected any https://example.com/wp-admin to https://example.com/blog/wp-admin with this change in my `nginx` conf,

```
location /wp-admin {
    rewrite ^/wp-admin(/.*)?$ /blog/wp-admin$1 permanent;
}
```

PS: Somehow I feel its not the best thing to do but only thing I could do for now. I hope someone will come up with a better solution.

Comment: please mark it as resolved, or we will reminded for ever to solve this

Comment: Okay. Marking it now but somehow it still doesn't feel right.